# div width increase on hover (without displacing inline divs)

Tags: html, css

Here is the link to my page mintrain.co.uk/indexsp

So, for the front-page I have made the four categories have width 25%.
On top of this, I've made the width double to 50% on hover.
Upon hovering, the div on the far right is pushed below the others.
How, using css, can I prevent this?
I had the idea of making the non-hovered div width decrease (to 16%) but i do not know how to achieve this.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In your page, you have multiple elements with same id (`#box`). That's not valid HTML, consider using class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using `flexbox`. Just add `display: flex` to container and `flex: 1` to childs to make layout you want. Then add bigger `flex` value to `:hover`. Like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.link {
  flex: 1;
  
  /* For demo only */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 40px;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.link:hover {
  flex: 1.5; /* Or any other value */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link"></div>
  <div class="link"></div>
  <div class="link"></div>
  <div class="link"></div>
</div>
```

For your site, just replace `.container` with `.boxes` and `.link` with `#box` (which isn't valid HTML on your site, having multiple same IDs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. works perfectly. just wondering about your commend on multiple IDs. it appears my understading was totally backwards. i thought IDs were used to apply* styles to multiple different elements with shared properties, and classes were unique. have i got it completely the wrong way round?

Comment: @JackScott Yep, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)